# css property value contains variable

Tags: css, less

How can I include a variable when setting a property value with less css. For example:

I want to set the background image on the right or on the left based on the variable `@direction`.

I've tried:

```
@direction:left;
background: url(../../images/downarrow_blue.png) no-repeat @direction white;
```

but it does not work.

Comment: how should that work? You have only given the half of the `background-position`. What is the other half? Top? Bottom? Center? A defined value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 issues:

1. To pass string value variables you should encloss them into single quotes. In your case it should be `@direction: 'left';`.
2. The background-position property accept two values corresponding to each axis. You need to pass something like: `@direction: 'left top';` or `@direction: 'right bottom';`.

Check the documentation related to variables: http://lesscss.org/#-variables